# A long-distance wireless charging product

Tags: wireless, smartphones, power-supply

Currently if you try to buy a "wireless charging" product to charge your phone, you'll mostly come across products based on the Wireless Power Consortium's [Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(standard)).  These products involve placing your phone on an inductive charging pad, which is hardly what the average person thinks of when they hear the phrase "wireless power."  It's only "wireless" in the sense that it does involve wires, not wireless in the sense of not requiring contact.

My question is, are there any long-distance wireless charging products, i.e. products which allow your phone to charge when it's in your hand and not in physical contact with the power transmitter?  So far I've come across two products which are releasing in the next year:

- Energous' [Far Field WattUp Transmitter](http://energous.com/technology/transmitters/#farfield), which has a range of 15 feet and is releasing in the first half of 2018
- [Motherbox](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/the-motherbox-true-wireless-charging-power-phone--2), which has a range of 20 inches and is releasing in September 2017

But are there any products which are available right now, or at least coming sooner than those two products?

Comment: I'm surprised there are *any*, even in the "coming soon" stage.  Far-field power transmission is much harder and less efficient than near-field transmission.

Comment: Well, there are definitely products in the coming soon stage; you can see videos of the Motherbox in action.  And you can see the power transmission rates; they're fairly good.

Comment: If you want to remodel your interior to have metal walls, you can build this right away:

http://www.iflscience.com/technology/disney-researchers-make-wireless-power-transfer-breakthrough/

Link described by URL

Comment: @RajHuff That's a prototype, not a commercially available product.  The two products listed in my question are or will be commercially available some time in the near future.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I didn't understand your question as purchasable consumer merchandise.  The link above references a working system in place now.  If I find a commercial product for you to buy I'll add an actual answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @RajHuff Well, this is a Hardware Recommendations site, so I thought it was understood that I wanted a product to buy.